# CSS media-queries within body

Tags: html, css, styles, media-queries

I have to override some the CSS-Styles within a template. This works fine, but I have the problem that these styles rely on media-queries, which seem not to work when the whole `<style>`-Block is within the body-tag.

When I do a..

```
<style type="text/css" >
 @media screen and(min-width: 30em) {
         .tabHeaderLink {
            width:20%;
            display:block;
            background:#D46365;
            height:50%; 
            }
        }
</style>
```

within the body, the style is not applied. Am I doing it wrong or is there a other solution?

Comment: "when the whole `<style>`-Block is within the body-tag" — Since the style element **is not allowed** there, solve the problem by writing valid HTML in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

the problem was indeed the missing space in

```
and(min-width: 30em)
```

it works with

```
and (min-width: 30em)
```